# Question on the Cantor set 4

Tags: real-analysis

This question is going to sound really obvious but I need a clear proof.

I'm trying to prove that if $x \in C$ then $1-x \in  C$. I am using induction to prove this. Using the induction hypothesis,

$x  \in  C_n \Rightarrow \, 1-x  \in  C_n$.

So, $x  \in  \left[\frac{j}{3^n},\frac{j+1}{3^n}\right]$ for some $j \in  \{0,1,...,3^n-1\}$.

Then, $1-x \in \left[1-\frac{j+1}{3^n},1-\frac{j}{3^n}\right]$.

Now, $\left[1-\frac{j+1}{3^n},1-\frac{j}{3^n}\right] \subseteq C_n$. Why is this true? I need a well argued proof of this.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: No, $1-x\in[1-\frac{j+1}{3^n},1-\frac{j}{3^n}]$. You've got the reversed. $\\$ Also, every $x\in[0,1]$ satisfies $x\in [\frac{j}{3^n},\frac{j+1}{3^n}]$ for some $j\in\{0,1,\dots,3^n-1\}$. To prove the induction step, you need to assume $x\in C_{n+1}$ implies $1-x\in C_{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I meant $1-x \in \left[1-\frac{j+1}{3^n},1-\frac{j}{3^n}\right]$.

Comment: Again, you're induction steps are wrong. You have to assume $x\in C_n\implies 1-x\in C_n$ and prove from there that $x\in C_{n+1}\implies 1-x\in C_{n+1}$. You haven't assumed *anything* about $x$. Finally, there are at least two ways of defining the $C_n$, so it would help to know how your source defines them.

Comment: You can use $$C_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot C_n \cup \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3}\cdot C_n\right).$$